# Find photo info page for Flickr profile image

Tags: search, images, url, flickr, avatar

Given a Flickr static image (like `http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8283/7753425102_02f23b5a21.jpg`), I know how to find the info page for that image (`http://www.flickr.com/photos/75151585@N07/7753425102/`), by extracting the image ID or by using a tool such as http://flickr.d6cn.com/.

But this doesn't work for profile images like `http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2213/buddyicons/30052849@N07.jpg`. How can I find the photo page for a profile image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

When you select an image for your buddy icon, Flickr will create a copy of it and allow you to play around with that.

Not all buddy or profile icons have a corresponding photo page under the account as it may not even be from that Flickr user's album.

But, you can at least find out who owns the profile when you hit them up.

Their profile image:

```
http://farm2.staticflickr.com/616/buddyicons/{profile-id}.jpg
```

Their profile page:

```
http://www.flickr.com/photos/{profile-id}/
```